# IEEEtran weird comma placement

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I just noticed a strange behaviour in IEEEtran bibliographies. This style puts the comma between the title and the following entry inside the quotation marks of the title and not behind it. his looks really wrong, because the comma is actually not part of the title, but of the enumeration of the items of an entry. Doesn't this make the citations wrong? And is it possible to change that?

This behaviour is independent of the entry type, e.g. article, book, phdthesis, inproceedings, ...

[image: IEEEtran bibliography with commas at the end of each title]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) According to [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/quotation-marks/), commas always are inside quotation marks in American English, which is the standard for IEEE.

Comment: @KersouMan Looks like an answer to me

Comment: I didn't know that. So I'll just leave the commas. Thank you! Unfortunately I cannot upvote your comment as I am new to this forum.

Comment: You found the error? Have the same problem!

Comment: As the guys mentioned above, commas (and dots) are always placed inside a quotation in AE. So, this style is correct.